# Attaching Parameterised Event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to attach an event to an element in JavaScript, problem is that I know only simple event attachment without parameters but here I want to attach an event with `this` parameter, something like shown below

```
element.addEventListener("onclick", 
                         function RemoveDirectory(this) {
                            alert(this);
                    });
```

here `this` should refer to `element` of course.

**Edit**

I tried using Jquery but since the element is not selected from the DOM it is a dynamically created element can some one tell me how can I use Jquery's `$("selector").click()` method with dynamically created elements which were created via `document.createElement("input");`

I tried this with jquery 1.7.2 NO LUCK

```
<script 
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" 
      type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
</script>

<div id="diver">
        Hello events !
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var btn = document.createElement('INPUT');
        btn.type = 'button';
        btn.value = "CLICK me";

        document.getElementById("diver").appendChild(btn);
        $(document).on('click', btn, function () {
            alert(this.value);
        });
</script>
```

problems with this are

1. Event is added to whole document instead of that dynamically added button only.
2. `this` keyword refers to `document` instead of that dynamically added button only.

Comment: Consider using jQuery, which does this for you for all event listeners, automatically.

Comment: Note that `addEventListener()` doesn't work with IE < 9

Comment: jQuery works just fine with dynamically created elements. Show more code and we can help you better.

Comment: @MattBall see my edit, I have shared my code, can you help me out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add event with  dynamically created element. try with jQuery **[.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

```
$(document).on('click','selector', function() {
  // here add your function
});
```

here ***selector*** will be your dynamically created element.

**Note :**  jQuery 1.7 is required

Comment: @Adnan , diEcho could you plz see my edit, problem is still alive.

Comment: set any ID ( if only 1 button ) or Class to the dynamically created element.

Comment: Yes it worked after applying a class to that button, Thanx all.

Answer (score 1):

You can either  use jQuery's `on()` method

```
$('#parent').on('click', 'input', function(){});
```

if you don't know the parent then you can use `document` instead.

or you can bind the handler after creating the element

```
$(document.createElement('input')).click(function(){});
```

Comment: You could find it useful that there is a shortcut for this in jQuery: `$("<input>")` which does exactly the same as `$(document.createElement('input'))`

Comment: @Esailija. Although I'm aware of that, thank you for mentioning it. I usually prefer `document.createElement()` because of the [notable performance difference](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-createelement/24), any thoughts?

Comment: Well, let's say you want to create 100k elements. You can do this in 1 second, but with jQuery shortcut it takes 1.25 seconds. Now, actually doing anything with these elements is going to take MINUTES (actually it would probably crash the browser even), so what was the point of saving 0.25 seconds? :P

Comment: @Esailija, true. I guess the word "performance" triggers the crazy region in my brain :D

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use closures ?

```js
var someRandomVariable = this;
element.addEventListener("onclick", function() {
    console.debug(someRandomVariable); //=> this
});
```

Comment: The variable `this` is a reference to the object to which the function belongs, it's *relative*. In the code above, i use the variable `someRandomVariable` to send the value of `this` to the function. That's called a *closure*.